# Accuracy of time series decomposition

Tags: time-series, decomposition

How to judge the accuracy of time series decomposition provided by R?

Because at different level of data aggregation and seasonality different repetitive patterns appear in seasonality index.

How to know that what is the best suited seasonality and granularity of data on which the decomposition is reliable?

I am trying to find signal to noise ration where signal is considered as trend + seasonality and noise is reminder component.

Is there any theoretical backing through which we can be confident of that at least we can rely on this decomposition for underlying patterns.